# How to work with the "eBay finding APi"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I`m relatively new to programming and I´m completely new to Stack overflow, so please be patient with me! Currently I work on a ASP.NET MVC project including the Ebay finding API.

**The goal i want to accomplish** is to create a Website on which you can search for different articles on Ebay and being able to use certain filters using the Ebay finding API. This is a training projekt for me, as the C# part of the whole thing is a good practice in my opinion. Unfortunately I´m stuck with the whole API connection to ebay part and havent done any C# programming myself.
Frankly i have no idea what im doing and I hope some of you may have an idea or some tips for me. I know I might be vague and I´m sorry, but i´m just at the beginning of programming.

**What have i done so far?**

I already registered on the ebay developers program and I already have my App ID, the Dev IDm the Cert ID and a Token.

**Important: I currently only work with the sandbox!**

I found a piece of code online which I´m using, but now im stuck. Obisously i filled in the IDs and the token but deleted it for this post. In the "Index" class at the end of my piece of code I entered the ID of a random Ebay article for testing purposes. When i debug I get this Exception:

**"eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.ApiException: 'This item cannot be accessed because the listing has been deleted, is a Half.com listing, or you are not the seller."**

I would really appreciate if someone can show me how to do it correctly or push me in the right direction. I have to admit that i find the whole Ebay API documentation etc. to be very confusing and I dind´t find any advice on how to start. I take any advice you guys can give me!

Here is the code I found and used so far:

```
    using System;    
    using System.Collections.Generic;    
    using System.Linq;    
    using System.Web;    
    using System.Web.Mvc;    
    using System.Windows.Forms;   
    using System.Resources;    
    using eBay.Service.Call;    
    using eBay.Service.Core.Sdk;    
    using eBay.Service.Core.Soap;    

namespace Ebay_API_Neu.Controllers    
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller    
    {   
    public GetItemCall getItemDataFromEbay(String itemId)    
    {    
    ApiContext oContext = new ApiContext();

    oContext.ApiCredential.ApiAccount.Developer = "//dev ID"; // use your dev ID

    oContext.ApiCredential.ApiAccount.Application = "//App ID"; // use your app ID

    oContext.ApiCredential.ApiAccount.Certificate = "//cert ID"; // use your cert ID

    oContext.ApiCredential.eBayToken = "//Token"; //set the AuthToken

    oContext.SoapApiServerUrl = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/wsapi";

    //set the Site of the Context

    oContext.Site = eBay.Service.Core.Soap.SiteCodeType.Germany;

    //the WSDL Version used for this SDK build

    oContext.Version = "735";

    //very important, let's setup the logging

    ApiLogManager oLogManager = new ApiLogManager();

    oLogManager.ApiLoggerList.Add(new eBay.Service.Util.FileLogger("GetItem.log", true, true, true));

    oLogManager.EnableLogging = true;

    oContext.ApiLogManager = oLogManager;

    GetItemCall oGetItemCall = new GetItemCall(oContext);

    //' set the Version used in the call

    oGetItemCall.Version = oContext.Version;

    //' set the Site of the call

    oGetItemCall.Site = oContext.Site;

    //' enable the compression feature

    oGetItemCall.EnableCompression = true;

    oGetItemCall.DetailLevelList.Add(eBay.Service.Core.Soap.DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll);

    oGetItemCall.ItemID = itemId;

    try   
    {    
    oGetItemCall.GetItem(oGetItemCall.ItemID);    
    }    
    catch (Exception E)

    {

    Console.Write(E.ToString());

    oGetItemCall.GetItem(itemId);    
    }    
    GC.Collect();

    return oGetItemCall;    
    }    
    public ActionResult Index()    
    {    
    getItemDataFromEbay("173354849991");

    return View();   
    }
```

Comment: " search for different articles on Ebay and being able to use certain filters using the Ebay finding API " 
If I understand your goals correct then you need: 
*findItemsByKeywords*(https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/findItemsByKeywords.html) 
and *findItemsByProduct*(https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/findItemsByProduct.html)

I have some test codes for product research but they are written in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error you are getting I would guess that you are trying to get information regarding a "random listing" you have not entered yourself on the eBay sandbox.  In order to use GetItem the listing you are retrieving has to have been created using your sandbox user id.

Take a look at the below link to API doc for GetItem() - specifically the requirements for "Testing GetItem".  If you think I might be correct then try creating a listing in the sandbox using either the Web Interface or eBay API AddItem() before retrieving it with GetItem().

https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getitem.html